# Документация для модуля pip

Tags: python

Где найти документацию для api модуля pip?

Comment: Какого рода документация интересует? Эта не подойдет? [pip.pypa.io](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @soon apidoc  ---

Answer (score 2):

Нету такой.

Если вы на самом деле хотите воспользоваться `pip` из кода, то вам нужен [`pip.main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950647/1026).

```
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('argh')
```

Comment: О-о, как раз то, что надо. Давно этот вопрос ищу. Плюсик. А для easy_install такое есть (пипа на 2.х нету)?

Comment: В смысле, пипа на 2.х нету?

Comment: В комплекте нету.

Comment: А.. Ну там аналогично: http://stackoverflow.com/a/935219/1026